# Filtering outliers in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to filter out rows with outliers from a specific column in a numpy array.

on the forum I have found a line that looks like this

`f_data = data[data[:,3]==1,:]`

while it seems to work I don't really understand how and could not really replicate it.

Would appreciate it if someone could break that line down and explain it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum. It's a Q&A site. The distinction may seem meaningless, but it's important.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial on numpy indexing

Comment: Please see [ask] for an introduction on how to provide sufficient information for a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That line of code filters rows in a 2D numpy array `data` based on the values in its 4th column (index 3). It keeps only the rows where the value in the 4th column is equal to 1.

- `data[:,3]` selects all rows and only the 4th column of data.
- `data[:,3]==1` creates a boolean mask that is True for rows where the
  value in the 4th column is equal to 1 and False otherwise.
- `data[data[:,3]==1,:]` uses that boolean mask to index into data,
  keeping only the rows where the mask is True

Answer (score -1):

This command does not particularly filter outliers. It just selects the rows in a 2D array (or ND with N>2) if the values in the fourth column are 1.

So unless this column is a flag with 1 when the row is not an outlier **in your dataset**, the code is likely not applicable to you.

Example:

```
data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 0],
                 [0, 1, 1, 1],
                 [0, 1, 0, 0],
                 [0, 0, 0, 1]])

# only keep the rows with 1 in the 4th column:
f_data = data[data[:,3]==1,:]
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: This does not answer the question because there is not much of a question to answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I initially started writing a comment but ran into the length limit. You should vote to delete the question, in the meantime this hopefully can help the asker to understand that it's likely a dead end to them (and why).